# GetDate() function and this query are correct?

Tags: php, sql-server

Is this query below correct and more specific the `TransferTime < (GetDate() - 3` ?

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('
    SELECT Class, TransferTime 
    FROM USERDATA 
    WHERE strUserId = ? 
      AND (TransferTime < (GetDate() - 3) OR TransferTime IS NULL)   
', $character);
```

Will it check if the `strUserID` and `transfertime` is less than 3 days since it doesn't really work exactly at 3 days ?

Answer (score 3):

`GETDATE() - 3` subtracts 3 days to the current date **and** time. If you need to use that filter for 3 days before, starting from `00:00:00.000`, then you need to first strip the `TIME` part of the `GETDATE()`. If using SQL Server 2008+, you can cast `GETDATE()` to `DATE`:

```sql
WHERE TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-3,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```

For previous versions, you can use:

```sql
WHERE TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE())-3,0)
```

Comment: I use MSSQL 2005, so my current query will substract 3 days including the hours and etc, for example today 7/8/2013 1:00 PM, so it will substract at 4/8/2013 1:00 PM or ?

Comment: @JohnMak As said on the answer, yes, it substracts 3 days to current date and time, it will leave it at `20130804 13:00:00.000`. If you don't want that, then use the second part of my answer to strip the time and leave it at `20130804 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Okay, I'll try and check it out. Also, can you edit your post to include 1 hour substract only from my current query ? It will be so much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @JohnMak So, you want to substract 73 hours instead of 3 days?

Comment: no, I want to substract only 1 hour from the current date and time. Like its my current default query but instead of 3 days to be just 1 hour.

Comment: @JohnMak That is a textbook use of `DATEADD` as I used it before. `DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())`

Comment: I cant use it like its my current one `(TransferTime < (GetDate() - 3)` ?????

Comment: @JohnMak No, that's what I said that you need to use `GETDATE()`, what is the issue with it?

Comment: So, I will use `DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())` instead of `GetDate() - 3` but is it secure and not vulnerable ? The query you told me `DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())` its secure ?

Comment: @John Secure means what? Vulnerable to what?

Comment: So, to sum it up I must use this for 1 day substract: `(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL)` for MSSQL 2005 or its not correct ?

Comment: @JohnMak Look, `DATEADD()` can be used to add or subtract years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc. If you need to subtract 1 day, then you use `DATEADD(DAY,-1,SomeColumn)`, you need to subtract 10 hours?, then use `DATEADD(HOUR,-10,SomeColumn)`, if you need to add 25 minutes, then use `DATEADD(MINUTE,25,SomeColumn)`, and so on

Comment: since they could never transferred before, so it will be null at first place ...

Comment: I understand, so I am curious why my current one `(GetDate() - 3)` didnt worked correctly ?

Comment: @JohnMak What do you mean??. I already told you, `GETDATE()-3` works for `GETDATE()` and subtracts 3 days to the current date and time. What is it that doesn't works??????

Comment: so to use other than days, I need to use your query you told me ?

Comment: @JohnMak I don't want to be rude, but did you read my comment?, it says very clearly how you can use that function. And even if I wasn't clear, you know you can read the documentation for [dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select GetDate() - 3
```

it will truly remove 72 hours from the current date+time

Comment: I need it for my query, not like this.

Comment: I think that op is worried about the time part of the condition

Comment: @John Mak, how can anyone tell if your query works for your undefined table and data? for the code you are unsure of, you can run it as I suggest to see what the actually value is.  how can I tell what TransferTime values you have?

Comment: I was asking if (GetDate() - 3) exactly how it is in my query is supposed to work as it should be (making the current date minus 3)

Comment: @John Mak, I'm saying that if you run `select GetDate() - 3` you will see that actual value that SQL Server is using in your query.  It will take the current date+time and subtract 72 hours.